# Repeatative crash for viewpager after release

Tags: android, google-play, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2, signed-apk

I just released a new version of my app on play store, I observed that I am constantly getting an crash for few users related to viewpager in my Activity, my app targetSdkVersion is 33

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
FragmentManager is already executing transactions
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.ensureExecReady (FragmentManager.java:1695)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction (FragmentManager.java:1725)
androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow (BackStackRecord.java:317)
androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer.updateFragmentMaxLifecycle (FragmentStateAdapter.java:752)
androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer$3.onStateChanged (FragmentStateAdapter.java:678)
androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent (LifecycleRegistry.java:360)
androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass (LifecycleRegistry.java:271)
androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync (LifecycleRegistry.java:313)
androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState (LifecycleRegistry.java:151)
androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent (LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart (Fragment.java:3167)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start (FragmentStateManager.java:588)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java:279)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStore.java:113)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1433)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManager.java:2977)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart (FragmentManager.java:2902)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart (FragmentController.java:274)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:359)
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java:248)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1432)
android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:7995)
```

Wherever i used viewpager2 it's working fine, and all this crashes just started after the new release.

Libraries:

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.5"
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.1"
```

I tried and found that it is suggested to use childFragmentManager for my adapter, but since my viewpager is in Activity I am using supportFragmentManager.

Can anyone please help me with this issue.

Comment: The `Fragment.performStart` means that you are inside a Fragment or are incorrectly using a Fragment's Lifecycle where you shouldn't be. Include your code where you define your ViewPager2, where you set up your adapter, and your adapter itself.

Comment: @ianhanniballake but my viewpager2 code is working fine, problem i See is just with the normal viewpager, which earlier didn't occured but since the new release it started all of sudden

Comment: Show your code.